# QNAP TS-EC1279U with X520-DA2 (10GBe) Loosing NIC conneciton after workstation reboot

Tags: nic, 10gbethernet, qnap

=== Configuration===

- Your Operating System you are using to access your NAS. Win 7
- NAS model: TS-EC1279U-RP
- Firmware Version/: 4.1.4
- Network Setup Single Port Static IP (192.168.1.199) (10GbE)

---

=== Storage ===

- QNAP - TS-EC1279U-RP
- Intel - X520-SR2
- Trancsiver - AFBR-703SDZ-IN2 (SFP)

---

=== Workstation ===

- Win 7 / i7
- Intel - X520-SR2 Trancsiver - AFBR-703SDZ-IN2 (SFP)
- Static ip (192.168.1.185) (10GbE)

---

They are directly connected via a fiber optic cable. The workstation and NAS have a static IP. When I setup the static IP on the NAS, I am able to connect & ping and all works well.

### Problem

If I reboot the workstation, all works well. If I shutdown the workstation and turn it on, I am unable to communicate with the NAS via (192.168.1.199) nor even ping. If I login into the QNAP, it show that it is connected.

[image]

I have to change the IP on the NAS to 192.168.1.198 and everything works again.

### Solution

I think my first step is to update the firmware on the X520-DA2. However I have looked everywhere and I cannot find the firmware. Can anyone point me to it please.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about this please. I have already submitted a ticket to QNAP support, however they are so slow.

Comment: I have resolved this issues, QNAP made some changes to their latest firmware

Answer (score 0):

QNAP link to firmware https://www.qnap.com/i/en/product_x_down/product_down.php?II=20

Intel link to flash the firmware for X520-DA2 
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19186/Intel-Ethernet-Connections-Boot-Utility-Preboot-images-and-EFI-Drivers

Comment: Hi, I have those links. I have update my QNAP firmware. Regarding the NIC. I have been here. I could not find the firmware at all. I downloaded File name: PREBOOT.EXE and extracted, but, not other information given. It seems to be badly explained.

Comment: Yes the website doesn't offer much in steps to take.  In the past with NAS's I have had to take the NIC, install the NIC on a workstation and update the firmware on the NIC while it is connected to a Windows workstation and then install it back in the NAS.

Comment: I have resolved this issues, QNAP made some changes to their latest firmware

Comment: Glad it is solved!